# 32 Feet.net Pair Without a pin

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, 32feet, pairing

Does anyone know how to pair to a device without a pin in 32 feet?

> bool isPaired = BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(device.DeviceAddress,
>   pin);

I have disabled pin or pass entry on the bluetooth module im using and windows pairs fine with it. I just cant seem to find documentation or examples of how to pair with the device with 32 feet without a pin. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using Win32 as their WIKI suggests? [BluetoothWin32Authentication](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/wiki/BluetoothWin32Authentication)

Comment: I havn't tried doing that one without a pin yet. Let me try real quick

Comment: I can't find anywhere in the link you provided on how to perform a request without a pin